# Shared Firefox Profile (Win10 & Linux) - Browser startup issue after switching OS

Tags: linux, windows-10, firefox, firefox-profile

I'm using a Notebook with Dual-Boot-OS, using Windows 10 and MX Linux (Debian based).

I've created a single Firefox profile folder that is used and shared on both systems (Firefox 71.0):

- the profile folder is stored on a separate (non-OS) NTFS partition
- both systems can access this partition right after login
- both Firefox installations are set up to use this profile folder

In general, this setup is working fine.

**However, there's a minor (annoying) problem that occurs every time I switch the OS:**

When launching the browser for the first time, all installed Apps (extensions) are missing. A simple restart of Firefox fixes this problem, after a second start, all Apps are back and working.

But after I switch the OS, on first Firefox start, they're gone again.

It doesn't matter if I switch from Linux to Windows or the opposite, all installed Apps are missing after the first start of the browser.

Other settings seem to be correct, looks like it's just about the installed Apps.

As this problem could be solved by restarting Firefox every time I switch the OS, it's "just" annoying - but I'd love to get this fixed.

**What I could find out:**

After switching the OS and starting Firefox, I've had a look in the profile directory to see what changes were made there. The first start of the browser touches only a few things.

In the profile directory, this files were changed:

- extensions.json
- search.json.mozlz4
- compatibility.ini
- parent.lock
- storage.sqlite

...and this folders:

- cache 2
- startupCache

For obvious reasons, I checked `extensions.json` and found hardcoded absolute paths to my profile directory in it.

- Path examples on Windows, after first start:

  ```
  D:\\SharedSystem\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\extensions\\[...etc...]
  file:///D:/SharedSystem/Mozilla/Firefox/extensions/[..etc...]
  ```
- Path examples on Linux, after first start:

  ```
  /media/vc1/SharedSystem/Mozilla/Firefox/extensions/[...etc...]
  file:///media/vc1/SharedSystem/Mozilla/Firefox/extensions/[...etc...]
  ```

A second browser start does not change this file again.

I don't know if the other files or directories are relevant or what I could check there.

**I'm not sure, but I can guess about a possible solution:**

The file `extensions.json` might cause my problem. It seems like extension paths are stored there and when switching the OS, Firefox automatically re-creates this file with the corresponding paths for the current OS.

**...but what can I do now, to somehow have this file working for both Linux and Windows?**

I'm clueless right now. Any ideas what could be done to avoid this first-startup-behaviour? The best solution would be one that's update safe - or at least easy to maintain.

---

**UPDATE:**

It's NOT `extensions.json` - I made a backup of this file, both Linux and Windows, and replaced the original one with the backup of the current OS, before starting the browser for the first time. It didn't work, Apps were still missing.

It has to be anything else in the profile dir, but guessing and poking around doesn't seem to help at this moment...

---

Thanks for any help or thoughts about this!

Comment: Is Firefox logged into a Firefox account?  Is it reloading the profile, which doesn't quite match between Windows and MX, from the Internet?  If you unplug the Ethernet (or equivalent for your wifi) and reboot, does your problem and known solution still occur?

Comment: @ChristopherHostage: I'm not using a Firefox account, i'm also not using "Firefox Sync" or similar. I just checked the offline behaviour, it's the same.

Comment: It may not be practical to share a profile between Windows and Linux.  Besides things like extension differences and paths, there may be issues with things like saved passwords.  The clean way to do it is with Firefox Sync.

Comment: @fixer1234: I do not save passwords in Firefox. I do not need to share sessions or similar. But i do use a customized `about:config` that i want to use on both systems and i want my security-related Apps, their config and their learned behaviour to be available on both systems. Maybe i got something wrong, but to me, there is not a single reason why i should use a mozilla service (a company that constantly loses the trust i had in it) for something where no service should be needed at all. But that's personal opinion - here, i'm looking for technical help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Done.**

I don't want to use Firefox Sync and i'll leave this here in case someone's trying similar things:

I had a closer look at the profile directory and the files that contain paths to the addons or OS relevant details.

This three are relevant:

- addonStartup.json.lz4 *(i missed that one in the beginning)*
- compatibility.ini
- extensions.json

1) I started Firefox twice in Windows to get it working correctly and saved this three files in a separate directory.

2) Then i did the same in Linux.

3) After that, i created autostart entries for both OS that copy this three files for the current OS in the Firefox profile directory, overwriting the existing ones.

So after logging into an OS, the matching profile files are copied where they belong and Firefox works right on first start.

In case of an update (that i'll have to install on both OS, of course), i can renew the backup of this three files - that's okay for me to do.

This way, i can use the same profile directory for both systems and avoid to use the Mozilla Sync service.